Randomize a value based on another cells value within 20%
I am mocking up patient fall data by age group for a sample report from an Excel dataset. What I'm trying to do is create a random value based on the cell contents from another cell. Cell D4 contains the value of 0.7% I want cell E4 to be a random value +-20% of D4. No other constraints exist.
Thank you, Doug
I did try variations of randbetween and rand but can't sort out how to do it based on another cell value.

Everything depends on decimal precision you want.
Lets take your number 0.7
-20% will be 0.56 and +20% will be 0.84
So you are seeking a random number between 0.56 and 0.84. While 0.64 would be desired output I believe 0.64321321456844 would not. And there are infinite decimal values between any 2 numbers.
RANDBETWEEN works only with integers, but there is a workaround.
Multiply RANDBETWEEN arguments by 10 power of decimal places (2 in this case) and divide result by same value (10 power of 2 = 100):
=RANDBETWEEN(0.56*100,0.84*100)/100

Random number will be with max 2 decimal places:

Lets make it more universal.
To find how many decimals there are use =LEN(TEXTAFTER(0.56,".")) and =LEN(TEXTAFTER(0.84,".")). Get max value with MAX formula and use it in POWER formula:
=LET(a,A2,b,a*0.8,c,a*1.2,d,MAX(IFERROR(LEN(TEXTAFTER(VSTACK(b,c),".")),0)),e,POWER(10,d),RANDBETWEEN(b*e,c*e)/e)

Result:

Also keep in mind that Excel decimal precision is limited to 15 digits.
